# How do I implement audio (pronounciation) functionality in online dictionary?

Tags: audio, dictionary

How would you implement word pronounciation functionality in an online dictionary site ? for example lets say, oxforddictionaries.com. they have this functionality where you can listen to how the given words are being pronounced. 
Well, do I have to record each word and save it in a folder and then link it up with the database? If that's the case then probably I would have to create a million .wav or any sound files for the million words in the database. or how would I sort this out ? How do u think oxforddictionaries.com implemented this functionality ?

Comment: It seems like the oxforddictionaries.com recordings were done by people, so indeed you'd have to hire some voice actors to pronounce the words. This isn't really a PHP question though.

Comment: the question is, how would you implement these kinda functionality in php, oxford site was just an example !!

Comment: Still, this has nothing to do with php or ajax.

Comment: @XoR Being rude to the people who you are asking to help you is not going to get you very far.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378126/wiktionary-api-for-pronunciation

Comment: yep apologies Mr Ynhockey .. !!

Comment: this isn't a programming question, you might be looking for library that can pronounce in machine way

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches

- Record each word (wav/mp3)
- Synthesize the sound based on the phonetic spelling.

The latter one feels quite unnatural, but a cheap solution. I know only about the Longman dictionary, they definitely record each word (and even whole sentences), with a couple of speakers, so you don't get bored..

Unless you want to do the synthesis in a plugin/widget, you probably end up with sound files with both approaches. You can simply play them with html/html5/flash players.